# Conditional WHERE clauses with TVP parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am building a recipe website and I am trying to create a stored procedure with a table-valued parameter but am running into some issues.

So the TVP is filled based on the checkboxlists that the user selects when he is trying to search for a recipe. I then would like to show recipes based on those selections, and for that reason I used a TVP in my stored procedure.

However I would like for the query to display all records (for each section) when the user does not select any options in one of the checkboxlists. When I try to do this the query immediately returns no results.

**TVP Setup and Logic**

| Category | Difficulty | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Meat | Easy | 0-15 min |
| **string.Empty** | Average | 30-45 min |
| Fish | Hard | **string.Empty** |

I want the procedure to filter each recipe by all the options selected in Category, Difficulty and Duration. I.e. in this case, I want the stored procedure to return all recipes that have Category = "Meat" or "Fish"; that have Difficulty = "Easy" or "Average" or "Hard" and have Duration = "0-15min" or "30-45min".

In case no values exist in Category, for instance, the stored procedure should return recipes from all categories, and only filter based on the columns that have values.

**Working code so far**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspPesquisarReceita (@TVP dbo.Filters READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, R.Rating, R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
        FROM dbo.Recipes R 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
        WHERE R.IDStatus = 1 
        AND (C.Category IN (SELECT Category FROM @TVP)
        AND DF.Dificulty IN (SELECT Dificulty FROM @TVP) 
        AND D.Duration IN (SELECT Duration FROM @TVP))
END
```

This code is working, only when I select options in all three of the checkboxlists (called Category, Dificulty and Duration).

**Code I have tried #1**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspPesquisarReceita (@TVP dbo.Filters READONLY)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, R.Rating, R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
            FROM dbo.Recipes R 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
            WHERE R.IDStatus = 1 
            AND (C.Category IN (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT Category FROM @TVP)
                                 THEN
                                  (SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, 
                                  R.Rating, R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
                                  FROM dbo.Recipes R 
                                  LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
                                  LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
                                  LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
                                  WHERE R.IDStatus = 1)
                                 ELSE (SELECT Category FROM @TVP) 
            AND DF.Dificulty IN (SELECT Dificulty FROM @TVP)
                                  *same as above*
            AND D.Duration IN (SELECT Duration FROM @TVP))
                                  *same as above*
    END
```

**Code I have tried #2** (only with example for Category)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspPesquisarReceita (@TVP dbo.Filters READONLY)
        AS
        BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Category FROM @TVP)
                SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, R.Rating, 
                R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
                FROM dbo.Recipes R 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
                WHERE R.IDStatus = 1
                AND DF.Dificulty IN (SELECT Dificulty FROM @TVP) 
                AND D.Duration IN (SELECT Duration FROM @TVP))
            ELSE
                SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, R.Rating, 
                R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
                FROM dbo.Recipes R 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
                LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
                WHERE R.IDStatus = 1 
                AND (C.Category IN (SELECT Category FROM @TVP)
                AND DF.Dificulty IN (SELECT Dificulty FROM @TVP) 
                AND D.Duration IN (SELECT Duration FROM @TVP))
    END
```

None of these two attempts have yielded any results. Can you help me out? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to show how your TVP would be populated in such a case. Because you are using your TVP to contain 3 different filter types, we need to see how the contents look when it contains different combinations e.g.  some categories, some difficulties, but no duration.

Comment: Yeah, that is going to be difficult. I am basically populating a DataTable using a foreach that adds the value of the checkboxlist item when it's selected to the corresponding DataTable column. I have also struggled to verify how the DataTable is being "displayed" when the user selects no values in one of the checkboxlists.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I am kind of new around here :) How exactly do you do that? I have tried to upvote but can't really do that yet because I lack reputation I think

Comment: Why not use three parameters? I would make things much easier.

Comment: @Dale nevermind, I was being stupid. I added a table with some values and explained how I would like for the stored procedure to work with the TVP. In fact, it makes things much easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonínLejsek because the user can select multiple options to search for recipes and passing only 3 parameters may not be enough. Imagine the user selects two options of each (Category, Difficulty and Duration)

Comment: You still need to define "Empty" - is that a null string, an empty string, or the string "empty" or something else?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just corrected it. When it is not filled, it is string.Empty, so an empty string effectively. Thank you for being so thorough!

Comment: Three table valued parameters are enough. You would not have to deal with empty values, just empty tables.

Comment: @Martunis99 its not about being thorough, we just plain and simple can't answer the question without the full information.

Comment: I see that now. I will be more extensive in my future posts. Thank you for the patience and assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest something like the following - although, as Dale points out, it would be kind of handy to see exactly how your @TVP value looks when it's populated with different combinations of filters.  However, in the interim, give this a try and see what results you get.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspPesquisarReceita (@TVP dbo.Filters READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT R.RecipeName, C.Category, DF.Dificulty, D.Duration, R.Rating, R.Publication, R.Photo, R.Views, R.IDRecipe
        FROM dbo.Recipes R 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Categories C ON R.IDCategory = C.IDCategory 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificulty DF ON R.IDDificulty = DF.IDDificulty
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Duration D ON R.IDDuration = D.IDDuration
        WHERE R.IDStatus = 1 
        AND
        (
            (C.Category IN (SELECT Category FROM @TVP))
            OR
            (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TVP WHERE LTRIM(ISNULL(Category, '')) <> ''))
        )
        AND 
        (
            (DF.Dificulty IN (SELECT Dificulty FROM @TVP))
            OR
            (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TVP WHERE LTRIM(ISNULL(Dificulty, '')) <> ''))
        )
        AND 
        (
            (D.Duration IN (SELECT Duration FROM @TVP))
            OR
            (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TVP WHERE LTRIM(ISNULL(Duration, '')) <> ''))
        )
END
```

Basically, I'm assuming that if a user hasn't ticked any options for a particular filter (Category, Difficulty or Duration), then there will be no rows in the @TVP table with a value in the corresponding column.  (If this assumption is incorrect, then we are back to Dale's suggestion of seeing more detail on how you are populating the @TVP variable - ie. your app-side code)

Comment: Hi @Craig! I have added a table with how my TVP is meant to work. I haven't tried your code but when I do I'll get back to you. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Martunis99 this should definitely work, the logic is correct i.e. it **is** attempting to meet your specification. i.e. each of the 3 filter conditions is either checking whether the condition is met, or if no condition exists, returning all. If its not working please create a [MRE] using dbfiddle or similar so we can see why. The second part of each `OR` means if nothing has been entered for that filter condition, that part of the `where` clause is essentially removed. Oh but there is one point, you probably need an `INNER JOIN` to ensure the filters are applied correctly.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, because it is indeed working like a charm. I missed some parenthesis while copying. Makes a lot of sense logically but I would never get to this by myself :) Thank you so much Craig, you beast, for the code! And @DaleK for your helpful guidance! I wish I could upvote the answer but I can't so I just accepted it! Could you please explain why I need an Inner Join to ensure the filters are applied properly?

Comment: If you start to have performance problems with this or just need something more advanced, have a look at dynamic sql commands via sp_executesql.

Comment: @Martunis99 I suggest reading up on joins, but basically an inner join requires a match on both sides of the join, a left join is happy with null on the right hand side.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I see. Good tip! I will look into it, thanks

Comment: @DaleK I see what you mean. I will look into it. Thank you!